# Put a Backbone.js View,Model,Router... inside an object with _.extend()

Tags: javascript, object, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm building an application and I'm using Backbone.js. 
Because I'm quiet new to Backbone, I have read there documentation, looked and tested multiple apps and read the Backbone patterns.

Now I'm starting to understand the whole backbone principal, but I have a little problem with something. I have a global object (example: `App`) and I put my views, models,... inside it (example: `App.Views.ListView`). Now the problem is that I need to extend these object, because there could be default values inside it.

So when I started, I had something like this

```
App.Views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

But now I want something like this

```
_.extend(App.Views.ListView, Backbone.View.extend({});
```

This doesn't work like I want it to. The App.Views.ListView exists (It's defined in a config file where you see the file object structure and the extending does something). The problem is that I can't  make an instance of the view (ex `new App.Views.ListView();`)

**Examples:**

The object that is created in my config

```
App:{
 Views:{
  ListView:{
   myVar: "hello"
   DeeperList: {
   }
  }
 }
}
```

If you look you see that the object App.Views.ListView contains a variable with the value hello and an object DeeperList. But inside this object I want to add my view without overwriting myVar and DeeperList. When you use `App.Views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({});` you will overwrite it, but is there way to avoid this. Like using extend...

Is the someone who also had this problem of who know how to solve it?

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the object you want:

```
App = {
    Views: {
        ListView: {
            myVar: "hello"
            DeeperList: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Just do a jQuery extend with the first parameter set as true and you'll deep extend/merge this namespace with another object/namespace

```
(function(App, ListView, undefined){
    $.extend(true, ListView, {
        'DeeperList': Backbone.View.extend({

        })
    });
})(window.App, App.Views.ListView);
```

For more information about javascript namespacing visit following interesting blog post: 
http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

If you don't use jQuery you can also use the extend function that is mentioned in the blogpost.

```
function extend(destination, source) {
    var toString = Object.prototype.toString,
        objTest = toString.call({});
    for (var property in source) {
        if (source[property] && objTest == toString.call(source[property])) {
            destination[property] = destination[property] || {};
            extend(destination[property], source[property]);
        } else {
            destination[property] = source[property];
        }
    }
    return destination;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, `App.Views.ListView` is kind of mixin. So you could do something like:

```
var App.Views.ExtendedListView = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend(App.Views.ListView, {
    newMethod: function () {
        // ...
    }
}));

var extListView = new App.Views.ExtendedListView();
```

It looks a little ugly, but it works. If you could show your `App.Views.ListView`, maybe we can to find a more beautiful decision.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but it still wants to overwrite my objects. I will add more information in my question.

Comment: Okay, but how do you want to use `App.Views.ListView` after extending it? It would be constructor for views or what?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone's [`extend`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1292) isn't the same as Underscore's [`extend`](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L666). Underscore's `extend` is little more than a `for` loop for (shallow) copying object properties:

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
  each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
    for (var prop in source) {
      obj[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```

Backbone's `extend` is a wrapper for its internal [`inherits` function](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1398):

```
var extend = function(protoProps, classProps) {
  var child = inherits(this, protoProps, classProps);
  child.extend = this.extend;
  return child;
};

//...

// Helper function to correctly set up the prototype chain, for subclasses.
// Similar to `goog.inherits`, but uses a hash of prototype properties and
// class properties to be extended.
var inherits = function(parent, protoProps, staticProps) {
  var child;
  // [Bunch of code for properly setting up the prototype chain and elided]...
  return child;
};
```

Take note of the `return child` calls in both `extend` and `inherits`: they both create and return something new, they don't modify their arguments.

The problem with using `_.extend` to mix a view "class" into an existing object:

```
_.extend(App.Views.ListView, Backbone.View.extend({});
```

is that `_.extend` doesn't do anything with the prototype, `_.extend` also doesn't magically convert an object into a function so you can't call `new` on what `_.extend` gives you. You can mix properties into a view "class" but you have to mix the properties into the `prototype` and the assign the view to its final destination so that you get a function in `App.Views.V`:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({ ... }); // Create the view.
_.extend(V.prototype, App.Views.V);    // Mix App.Views.V into its prototype.
App.Views.V = V;                       // Replace App.Views.V with our view function.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5KSbw/

All that chicanery is going to confuse the poor soul that has to extend and maintain this code so I'd recommend against it. You'd be better off using a separate object to hold your defaults:

```
var DEFAULTS = {
    Views: { ... }
};
```

and then reference those defaults explicitly:

```
App.Views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    myVar: DEFAULTS.Views.ListView.myVar,
    //...
});
```

You will have a problem with `DeeperList` though, you'd have to explicitly copy its content to avoid alter the `DEFAULTS` version if you just copied a reference:

```
App.Views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    DeeperList: _.extend({}, DEFAULTS.Views.ListView.myVar),
    //...
});
```

And if `DeeperList` contained objects or arrays, you'd need to use jQuery's [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) with `true` as the first argument to get a deep copy:

```
App.Views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    DeeperList: $.extend(true, {}, DEFAULTS.Views.ListView.myVar),
    //...
});
```